# Loading Excel values to Teradata

Tags: excel, import, teradata

The Excel file I am using has cells which contains multiple lines typed in by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. When this Excel is load into teradata, these multiple lines in single cell should reflect in single cell in the teradata table also. But instead, it is getting loaded as several rows. How to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Find & Replace (aka Ctrl+H). Type Ctrl+J in the Find what: text box and put a space or some alternate character in the Replace with: text box. Make sure that the Match entire cell contents is not active and click Replace All.

This effectively changes all instances of line feeds (aka `CHAR(10)`, `vbLF` or ASCII 0010) into spaces. If spaces will not suit your purposes, choose another character or text string.